# Trying to split out self-referential data into a seperate struct

Tags: struct, reference, rust, lifetime

I want to be able to store a struct called `Child` inside a `Parent`, where the `Child` contains a reference back to the parent.

It works if I have the `Child` structs directly inside the parent like this:

```
struct Parent<'s> {
    cache: RefCell<Vec<Child<'s>>>
}
```

But if I move the `Vec` into a separate struct, then it will fail to compile with lifetime errors.

```
struct Parent<'s> {
    cache: RefCell<Cache<'s>>
}

struct Cache<'s> {
    children: Vec<Child<'s>>
}
```

**It is possible to make this example work with the separate structs?**

Here's the [full working code](http://is.gd/5BiZnj), which compiles fine. When move the `children` into the separate struct then it [fails](http://is.gd/Kpijfh).

**My analysis of the problem:**

When `Parent` contains `children` directly, `'s` is the same lifetime as the scope of the `Parent` struct itself, thus I can call methods that take `&'s self` on `Parent`.

When `Parent` contains `Cache` which contains `children`, `'s` is the same lifetime as the scope of the `Cache` struct, which is created before `Parent`, thus it is impossible to call methods on `Parent` that take `&'s self`. Attempting to do so gives the error

```
<anon>:33:15: 33:16 error: `p` does not live long enough
<anon>:33     let obj = p.create_object();
                        ^
<anon>:30:48: 38:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 30:47...
<anon>:30     let cache = Cache { children: Vec::new() }; // the lifetime `'s` is essentially from this line to the end of the program
<anon>:31     let mut p = Parent { cache: RefCell::new(cache) }; // although the Parent instance was created here, 's still refers to the lifetime before it
<anon>:32     // this fails because p doesn't live long enough
<anon>:33     let obj = p.create_object();
```

I need a way of shortening `'s` to the scope of `Parent`, not the scope of the `Cache`.

**Disclaimer:**
This question is very similar to one I asked earlier (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579518/rust-lifetime-error-with-self-referencing-struct?noredirect=1#comment53014063_32579518) that was marked as duplicate. I've read through the answer and I believe I'm beyond that as I **can** get the lifetimes of references right (as shown in my first example). I'm asking this (now slightly different) question again because I now have a concrete example that works, and one that doesn't work. I'm sure that what can be done with one struct can be done with two, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can make it compile by forcing the `Cache` and the `Parent` to have the same lifetime by defining them in the same `let` binding.

```
fn main() {
    let (cache, mut p);
    cache = Cache { children: Vec::new() };
    p = Parent { cache: RefCell::new(cache) };
    let obj = p.create_object();

    let c1 = Child { parent: &p, data: 1 };
    p.cache.borrow_mut().children.push(c1);
}
```

Here, we're essentially declaring a destructured tuple and then initializing it. We cannot initialize the tuple directly on the `let` binding:

```
    let (cache, mut p) = (Cache { children: Vec::new() }, Parent { cache: RefCell::new(cache) });
```

because the initializer for `p` references `cache`, but that name is not defined until the end of the `let` statement. The separate initialization works because the compiler tracks which variables are initialized; if you swap the order of the assignments, you'll get a compiler error:

```
<anon>:31:38: 31:43 error: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `cache` [E0381]
<anon>:31     p = Parent { cache: RefCell::new(cache) };
```